# BadMethodCallException Method [insert] does not exist. in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

i have blade file in modal form and a addbusiness model and Post controller that insert to database but when i try insert it show me this error `BadMethodCallException
Method [insert] does not exist.` but when i look at my controller there is a function as `insert` here is my controller code `

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Post;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\DispatchesJobs;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\AuthorizesRequests;
use Illuminate\Http\Requests;
//use DB;

use Session;

class addbusinessController extends Controller
{

    public function index(){
        //fetch all posts data
        $posts = Post::orderBy('created','desc')->get();

        //pass posts data to view and load list view
        return view('posts.index', ['posts' => $posts]);
    }

    public function details($id){
        //fetch post data
        $post = Post::find($id);

        //pass posts data to view and load list view
        return view('posts.details', ['post' => $post]);
    }

    public function add(){
        //load form view
        return view('posts.add');
    }

    public function insert(Request $request){
        //validate post data
        $this->validate($request, [
            'Fname' => 'required',
            'content' => 'required'
        ]);

        DB::table(' bussiness')->insert(
            ['owner_id' => 3, 'bus_name' => 'Fname',]
        );

        //get post data
        /*$postData = array(
            'title' => $request->input('title'),
            'content' => $request->input('content'),
        );*/
        $postData = $request->all();

        //insert post data
        Post::create($postData);

        //store status message
        Session::flash('success_msg', 'Post added successfully!');

        return redirect()->route('dashboard');
    }

    public function edit($id){
        //get post data by id
        $post = Post::find($id);

        //load form view
        return view('posts.edit', ['post' => $post]);
    }

    public function update($id, Request $request){
        //validate post data
        $this->validate($request, [
            'title' => 'required',
            'content' => 'required'
        ]);

        //get post data
        $postData = $request->all();

        //update post data
        Post::find($id)->update($postData);

        //store status message
        Session::flash('success_msg', 'Post updated successfully!');

        return redirect()->route('dashboard');
    }

    public function delete($id){
        //update post data
        Post::find($id)->delete();

        //store status message
        Session::flash('success_msg', 'Post deleted successfully!');

        return redirect()->route('posts.index');
    }

}`
```

here is my add business model

```
<?php
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class addbusiness extends Model
{
      //fillable fields
    protected $fillable = ['Fname', 'staffphn'];
}
`
```

and my modal form looks like this

```
  <script>
  function AddNewBus(){
        var title = '<center>New Business</center>';
        var size='large';
       var content = '<form action="{{ route('addbusiness') }}" id="UpUser" method="post">'+
          '<center><label id="msg1"></label></center>'+
          '<div class="form-group has-feedback">'+
         ' {{ csrf_field() }}'+
            '<input type="text" class="form-control" name="Fname" id="Fname" value="" placeholder="Business Name" required />'+
            '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-briefcase form-control-feedback"></span>'+
          '</div>'+

          '<div class="form-group has-feedback">'+
            '<select class="form-control" id="ubuscountry" name="ubuscountry" onchange="setState(this);"  >' +
              '<option value="">--Select Your Country--</option>'+

            '</select><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user form-control-feedback"><label style="color:red;">*</label></span>'+
          '</div>'+
           '<div class="form-group has-feedback">'+
            '<select class="form-control" id="ubusstate" name="ubusstate"  >' +
              '<option value="">--Select Your State/Province--</option>'+


          '</select>'+
            '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-phone form-control-feedback"><label style="color:red;">*</label></span>'+
          '</div>'+
          '<div class="form-group has-feedback">'+
            '<input type="number" class="form-control" name="staffphn" id="staffphn" value="" placeholder="Phone Number" />'+
            '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-phone form-control-feedback"><label style="color:red;">*</label></span>'+
          '</div>'+
          '<div class="form-group has-feedback">'+
            '<input type="email" class="form-control" name="staffmail" id="staffmail" value="" placeholder="Email" />'+
            '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope form-control-feedback"></span>'+
          '</div>'+
          '<div class="form-group has-feedback">'+
            '<textarea name="Address" id="Address" class="form-control" placeholder="Address with LAND MARK"></textarea>'+
            '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home form-control-feedback"><label style="color:red;">*</label></span>'+
          '</div>'+

          '<div class="row">'+
            '<!-- /.col -->'+
            '<div class="col-xs-4 pull-right">'+
              '<button type="submit"  name="addbus" value="kk" class="btn btn-success btn-block btn-flat">Add Business</button>'+
            '</div>'+
          '</div>'+

       '</form>';
        var footer = '<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>';

              setModalBox(title,content,footer,size);
              $('#myModal').modal('show');
      }
</script>
```

please any help and proper documentation would be appreciated as am new to laravel and have been on this issue for some days.

UPDATED
here is my route code

```
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index')->name('dashboard');

Route::post('addbusiness', 
  ['as' => 'addbusiness', 'uses' => 'PostsController@insert']);
```

Comment: Where is your route for POST? Can you show your route file?

Comment: You also might want to take a look at the laravel documentation regarding [resource controller](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/controllers#resource-controllers). This will help clean up your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The route you show calls the insert method in the postsController:

```
'PostsController@insert'
```

But the insert method you showed us is in the `addbusinessController`.  From the code you've show us it sounds like this really should be in addbusinessController, so you should update your route to use it.

```
Route::post('addbusiness', 
    ['as' => 'addbusiness', 'uses' => 'addbusinessController@insert']);
```

Comment: have adjusted my route and have also created my addbusiness controller but i still error Class App\Http\Controllers\addbusinessController does not exis

Comment: `created my addbusiness controller`? You posted an existing addbusiness controller in your question: `class addbusinessController extends Controller` ... ?

Comment: thanks a million finally got it working,the issue was that in my app/Http/controller.. no addbusiness controller,it was Post controller that i used so i had to rename it and it worked fine.thumbs up

Answer (score 1):

I think you may want to use [named routes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/routing#named-routes)

So your routes would look something link

`Route::post('addbusiness', 'PostsController@insert')->name('addbusiness');`

Then the `{{ route('addbusiness') }}` helper should return the correct URL for you.

Hope that helps.